# How to open the same file as two separate buffers so that modifying one does not modify the other?

Tags: buffers

I am debugging an ocaml program with `M-x camldebug` while adding comments to the source code and the debugger shows incorrect positions in my tuareg/merlin window. It shows the positions as present in the original source file that do not match the edited file.

As a workaround, I would like to have my file opened in one buffer (the one I'm using with the debugger), and have another buffer with the same file opened that is not synchonized with the first one, i.e., as if it was open in a separate process and without changes in one buffer appearing in the other. Then, I'd just save my files after I'm done debugging.

I tried `C-x 4 c`, but that still makes changes in one buffer appear in the other. I have an obvious workaround of copying the file to scratch to edit it and then back again, but I am searching for a cleaner way.

Comment: Try `M-: (setq buffer-file-name nil) RET` in the debugger's buffer.  That will enable you to visit the file in a new buffer for editing.  It's unclear to me whether this would break the debugger's connection with the original buffer, though.

Comment: If it's a problem, you could alternatively leave the debugger's buffer alone, switch to a new empty buffer, use `M-x set-visited-file-name`, and then `M-x revert-buffer`.

Comment: I feel like there ought to be an easier existing way of doing this; but if there is then I'm not seeing it... I think most of the related functions go via `find-file-noselect` which implements the "If a buffer exists visiting FILENAME, return that one" behaviour.

Comment: I tried using the method in the first comment: opened file in two buffers (1) (2), set `buffer-file-name` to `nil` in (2) (the buffer that the debugger was using to show currently debugged code) and made changes in (1). It worked separately. I saved (1), prompted a few times where do I want to save it. Then, the debugger started following the code in (1) instead of (2), i.e., in the freshly saved buffer. So, as long as I save after finishing debugging the file, it works for me. I'll check second comment now.

Comment: I tried the second method - `C-x b` to open buffer named `-`, then `M-x set-visited-file-name` to my file, then `M-x revert-buffer` and it loaded the file that was editable separately. However, then the debugger started using that buffer instead of the originally opened one. The problem is that after saving the one not used by the debugger, it started asking for confirmation to reload from disk on each debugger step. Probably debugger kept triggering some kind of refresh. Not sure how it decides which buffer to use.

Comment: The method from the first comment works for me and if you'd be willing to copy it to an answer, I'd like to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the experimentation in the comments, the following worked, albeit with a few rough edges.

In the debugger's buffer, use:

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(setq buffer-file-name nil)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

That then enables you to visit the file again in a separate new buffer for editing, with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>.

---

The reported result was that, as desired, it was possible to edit in the new buffer without affecting the buffer being used by the debugger; however *saving* the new buffer caused the debugger to 'notice it' and start using it instead of the original buffer, so it was necessary to not save the changes until debugging was completed.